# GenStage partition dispatcher for multiple consumers?

Tags: elixir

Let's say producer gets event that looks like this:

```
%{somedata: [], analyze: true, test: true}
```

And I have 2 different types of consumers. First one only cares about event if `analyze: true` and other one if `test: true`

I can figure from documentation how to send event to 1 partition(producer), can I send to both if event analyze and test is both true? Or to none if both are false.

Other options are to: Broadcast to all and skip work in consumers if wrong type, which doesn't sound like a good idea - OR having different producers for different kinds of work.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while. Had a similar problem, and I solved this problem by using a `GenStage.BroadcastDispatcher`.

This one allows for multiple subscribers to receive the same message.
But it allows for routing logic using a `:selector` option.
Go checkout the documentation on [`GenStage.BroadcastDispatcher`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.BroadcastDispatcher.html) to read more about its behaviour.

On the subscription logic, I then have the following code, leveraging the `:selector` option of the broadcast dispatcher.

Given I have 3 consumers. An `analyze_consumer`, `test_consumer` and `general_consumer`:

```
# this one will receive each message that has a value at :analyze
GenStage.sync_subscribe(analyze_consumer,
                        to: producer_pid,
                        selector: &(&1.analyze))

# this one will receive each message that has a value at :test
GenStage.sync_subscribe(test_consumer,
                        to: producer_pid,
                        selector: &(&1.test))

# this one will receive all messages
GenStage.sync_subscribe(general_consumer,
                        to: producer_pid)
```

Hope this helps.